# What ninject binding should I use?

Tags: c#, ninject

```
public AccountController(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore)
    {
        //uncommenting the following line, uses the correct context, but
        //unit testing fails to work, as it is overwritten, so I need to use IoC 
        //to  inject

        //userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());

        UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
```

What should my ninject binding look like?  The only thing that I could get to even compile looks like the following, but that is not getting the correct context.

```
        kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

which is binding to something, but not the correct context used in the commented out line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `ConstructorArgument`

```
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>()
    .To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument(new ConstructorArgument("context", new ApplicationDbContext())
```

**But...**

In reality, you should **also** inject the dependency in your `UserStore<ApplicationUser>`, by binding `ApplicationDbContext`. The framework will then construct the whole graph for you:

`kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf()`

Comment: That worked, but the second line wasn't necessary, though I will take your word that I probably need it.  A brief google search isn't turning up any simple guides for WithConstructorArgument.  I'll keep looking.

Comment: BTW, what do you mean by the whole graph?

Comment: Your whole dependency graph. A depends on B that depends on C and so on. Having configured all bindings properly, when you create A via the container, B is injected into A and C is injected into B.

Answer (score 0):

From cvbarros answer we came up with the following:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("context", context => kernel.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

This allows the `ApplicationDbContext` to be injected and/or the `UserManager` to be injected. It also allows the `UserManager` to get the `ApplicationDbContext` from the dependency injector instead of creating a new instance.

Note, this code goes in the /App_Start/NinjectWebCommon.cs file

Comment: ApplicationDbContext in SingletonScope seems a bit dangerous to me.

Comment: Answer updated based on Ahmet's comment. InSingletonScope was not at all what we wanted. We were looking for InRequestScope. InSingletonScope caused a number of issues with the application. Thanks for the comment Ahmet.