# What does kernel.Bind<SomeType>().ToSelf() do?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject

I understand the following Ninject registration:

```
kernel.Bind<ISomeType>().To<SomeTypeImplementation>();
```

which tells Ninect to fulfill requests for **ISomeType** by using **SomeTypeImplementation**.

However I'm not sure what the following is good for.

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf();
```

Which was suggested that I use from this question:
[What ninject binding should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21939051/what-ninject-binding-should-i-use)

Comment: The type you use in `Bind<T>` is used as key. That's the type that will be resolved. Ninject 'knows' about that bind-type, not about the to-implementation. It just uses that to-implementation to construct the type. But sometimes you want to register some concrete type and have consumers that depend on that concrete type; not on one of its interfaces. For that you use `Bind<MyType>().ToMyType>()` or its shortcut: `Bind<MyType>().ToSelf()`.

Answer (score 3):

It makes ApplicationDbContext "self-bindable". If you don't have an interface to bind to, you can bind to the class itself. It's more useful if you add a scope to the call such as:

```
kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
```

Any time it sees the ApplicationDbContext that needs to be injected, it will reuse the same object as long as it is in the same HTTP request.

The default scope is transient, which means that any time a class requests ApplicationDbContext it will create a new instance of it. This can be problematic if you have two classes that both need to use the context in the same transaction. That is why you will often see it done with InRequestScope().

Comment: These were some great answers, but could you point me to some sources that explain this in more detail?

Answer (score 3):

By *self-binding* a type, you enable that type for the following:

1. Lifecycle Management by the container.
2. Enable the container to inject dependencies into other types that depend on the *self-bound* type, and inject dependencies of this type into its instances likewise.

Very useful if you just have one single implementation or you don't need to use abstractions for some reason.